# How to write text vertically in html?

Tags: css, html

[image]

Here is an example of what and how i need the text to appear in a td in html table

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264527/vertical-text-direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add spaces in between the letters

  ```
  txt.split('').join(' ')
  ```
- Set the width of the container to 1em

---

[image]